# SQL Query Optimisation String Manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run the following SQL statement which works fine in returning what I need however I'm not confident that it is the most efficient or optimised way of achieving the result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING((SELECT SUBSTRING(Quest_Fullpath, 13 + 1, LEN(Quest_Fullpath)) 
FROM Quest_Lookup 
where SUBSTRING(Quest_Fullpath, 13, 1) = ':'), 0, CHARINDEX (':', (SELECT SUBSTRING(Quest_Fullpath, 13 + 1, LEN(Quest_Fullpath)) 
FROM Quest_Lookup 
where SUBSTRING(Quest_Fullpath, 13, 1) = ':'))) FROM Quest_Lookup WHERE (SELECT SUBSTRING(Quest_Fullpath, 13 + 1, LEN(Quest_Fullpath)) 
FROM Quest_Lookup 
where SUBSTRING(Quest_Fullpath, 13, 1) = ':') LIKE 'Man%'
```

**Clarification**: The above statement is a combination of the two SQL statements below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(Y, 0, CHARINDEX (':', Y)) FROM Quest_Lookup WHERE Y LIKE '0%'


Y = SELECT SUBSTRING(Quest_Fullpath, 13 + 1, LEN(Quest_Fullpath)) 
   FROM Quest_Lookup 
   where SUBSTRING(Quest_Fullpath, 13, 1) = ':'
```

Is there a cleaner way to run this in terms of performance and/or syntax?

**Sample Data**

> 01 Testing this string:Finance and Tax:Europe:Netherlands:Live Programmes and Projects
>
> 02 Something:Manage programmes and projects:Asia:Nepal:Live Programmes and Projects

I run the query on the data above which represents a folder structure separated by a colon. The query returns the string between both colons filtering out all the data on either side depending on which position in the sample data the substring operation is performed on. The position is 13 in this case but this changes in real time as it represents the length of text typed in a textbox.

Comment: why don't you create a user defined function to get it without complexion the query ?

Comment: Yeah, you're right - it's not the most optimised way to get the result. The most optimised way is to have your data normalised instead of putting multiple values in one string column. If `Quest_Lookup` ever gets big, you won't have any way of scaling the performance well.

Comment: Could you show some sample data and what is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

[DRY](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Don't_repeat_yourself) it up a bit by adding an [indexed computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx) for `RIGHT(Quest_Fullpath, 13)` (or `RIGHT(Quest_Fullpath, 14)` - don't really follow your code) and rewrite your query accordingly.

Comment: Adding a computed column cannot be a good solution. What if he has other queries (`RIGHT` 3/4/5/etc.) and he for sure has. You do not know how big is his tables, you are not familiar with how many indexes this table has, you have no idea about how often data is inserted/update/deleted? You do not know if this is homework or production environment? And more and more ... and you advice him to create a index ...